# Can someone explain this dictionary behaviour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
>>> data = "0:1:2"
>>> h2 = data[0]
>>> a = {0: "... ", 1: "..- ", 2: ".-."}
>>> print (0 in a)
True
>>> print (h2)
0
>>> print (h2 in a)
False
>>> print (a.keys())
dict_keys([0, 1, 2])
```

Has something gone wrong with the aliasing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`h2` is a *string* value, but your dictionary keys are *integers*. Integers and strings cotaining only digits *print* the same, but are *not* the same type and unlike JavaScript, Python does not consider them equal or coerces between integers and strings.

Explicitly convert your string to an integer first:

```
>>> type(h2)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(next(a))  # first key in a
<class 'int'>
>>> int(h2) in a
True
>>> a[int(h2)]
'... '
```

To see the difference between different types properly, use `repr()` when printing:

```
>>> print(repr(h2))
'0'
>>> print(repr(0))
0
```

Note the quotes around the string value. The Python interactive shell uses `repr()` by default when echoing values (everything except `None` is echoed):

```
>>> 'a string value'
'a string value'
>>> 42
42
```